# How to replace url path parameter

Tags: azure-api-management

How to replace value of `tenantId` in the following url: `/{tenantId}/users`? I need to replace it with a value from jwt token. It's trivial for query param, but path params are not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting you right, you want to rewrite the uri in the inbound section?
If your url is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/{tenantId}/users
```

Then you can rewrite the Uri with following command:

```
<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(context.Request.MatchedParameters["tenantId"], "<YOUR-JWT-TOKEN-VALUE>"))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```